# Progress Bar reset in Flex

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4.5

I have been working on resetting a progressBar in flex, but the thing is that progressbar correctly displays the bytes loaded while the file is downloaded for the first time, but for other consecutive file downloads, it just stays at 100% although the file is downloaded, How do I reset the the progressbar so that it correctly shows the progress for other files too.

I have tried using `pb.setProgress(0,100)` before the progressbar starts to set the progress to zero but it also does not helps.

Also I have set the mode to `manual`.

Ok here is what I have done :

Have a **progress Event** in which I am setting the progress of the progressBar as :

```
public function progressHandler(event:ProgressEvent):void
            {                               
                pb.width=300;
                pb.height=30;
                pb.labelPlacement="center";
                pb.mode="manual";
                pb.setProgress(event.bytesLoaded, event.bytesTotal);    
            }
```

Also in the **open event** I am calling a title window and adding the progress bar into it and then popping it using the popup manager as :

```
public function openWindow(event:Event):void {
                tWin.title = "Please Wait";
                tWin.width=400;
                tWin.height=100;
                tWin.addChild(pb);
                PopUpManager.addPopUp(tWin, this, true,PopUpManagerChildList.POPUP);
                PopUpManager.bringToFront(tWin);
                PopUpManager.centerPopUp(tWin); 

            }
```

Then finally in the **complete event**, i am removing the popupmanager and setting the progress to be zero as :

```
public function completeHandler(evt:Event):void {
PopUpManager.removePopUp(tWin);
pb.setProgress(0,100);
}
```

But still the progress bar remains at 100% for any consecutive file downloads.
Any help..??

Comment: If all else fails; you could destroy the old one and recreate it.

Comment: Are you sure you are correctly re-referencing everything correctly ?  I could see an issue whereby the listeners and objects aren't re-setup correctly causing a 100% to stay.  You may want to post some of your AS3 code where you link up to the download object.

Comment: @Reboog711 how do I destroy the progressbar..??

Comment: @FlexFiend have added the code, please suggest what can be done.

Comment: @abhi191 To destroy the old progress bar, usually you can just instantiate a new one:  `tWin.addChild(new ProgressBar())`. But in reality, you might have to do a little more work than that to initialize the component or inform other parts of your application that there is a new instance of the progress bar (and that they should add event listeners to it and/or remove the event listeners from the original one, etc.)

Comment: @abhi191  I don't see too much wrong with your code, but I do have misgivings about the setting of the height and width of the ProgressBar in the event handler.  Usually, that stuff is set somewhere else, and the only thing the event handler does is work with things that are dependent on the progress.

Comment: Nope still doesn't work.
Any more suggestions..??